# How do I create a TypeScript type definition for a stateless React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-definition

I'm trying create type definitions for an existing suite of *stateless* React components, so I can generate documentation automagically and to improve intellisense in my team's tooling.

An example component could look like this:

**myComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export const MyComponent = ({ prop1, prop2, prop3 }) => (
    <div>
        { prop1 ? prop2 : prop3 }
    </div>
);
```

I would like my type definition to:

- Define which props are allowed (and which are required)
- That it will return JSX

Looking at [this](https://medium.com/@iktakahiro/react-stateless-functional-component-with-typescript-ce5043466011) example of creating React components using TypeScript, I discovered the type: `React.SFC`.

I tried to use this in my definition:

**index.d.ts**

```
declare module "MyComponent" {
    import React from 'react';

    interface MyComponentProps {
        prop1: boolean;
        prop2?: string;
        prop3?: string;
    }

    export const MyComponent = React.SFC<MyComponentProps>
}
```

But I'm getting the linting error `[ts] '(' expected.`

I'm pretty new to TypeScript and I am clearly missing something, but I can't find any articles on creating type definitions for stateless components.

**EDIT**
To be clear, I don't want to rewrite my components in TypeScript. I want to create a type definition file (*.d.ts) for an existing ES6 stateless component.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling, we have settled on the following set up.

```
import React from 'react';

export interface MyComponentProps {
    prop1: boolean;
    prop2?: string;
    prop3?: string;
}

declare const MyComponent: React.SFC<MyComponentProps>

export default MyComponent
```

The inspiration for this was taken from:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/material-ui/index.d.ts

It works well with TypeDoc and also VS Code's intellisense.

I believe `export default` was the key to cracking intellisense here.

Comment: What file did you put this in, and where is that file in your project?

Comment: I our case, the file was named "index.d.ts", which matches the dist/index.js file in question.

Comment: But you can define the typing file in your package.json, like so: "typings": "index.d.ts"

Comment: How do you guys would do to add a type annotation file to a functional component with state (using useState)?

Comment: I don't think the type definition would change, unless the props changed?

Comment: That was really helpful, i was stuck on that declare module thing that wouldn't produce anything good, now i can type all these sh*tty components without having to rewrite them all! Thanks a bunch 

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
declare module "MyComponent" {
  import React from 'react';

  interface MyComponentProps {
    prop1: boolean;
    prop2?: string;
    prop3?: string;
  }

  export const MyComponent: (props: MyComponentProps) => React.SFC<MyComponentProps>
}
```

From official React page recommendations [Type Definitions](https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html#type-definitions)

Comment: You are declaring a HOC, a function that returns a stateless functional component

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `var MyComponent: React.SFC<MyComponentProps>;`

You might consider rewriting existing code in typescript anyway just to see what kind of definitions tsc would generate. Then discard the code and keep just the definitions.

Comment: If I define:
var MyComponent: React.SFC<MyComponentProps>;

Will the be automatically exported?

Ah that's a cool idea - I didn't realise TypeScript would output something which was human readable.

Answer (score 1):

Its, `:`, not `=`.

```
export const MyComponent:React.SFC<MyComponentProps> = ({ prop1, prop2, prop3 }) => (
<div>
    { prop1 ? prop2 : prop3 }
</div>
);
```

Comment: I've updated my question, but I think this is rewriting the component in typescript. I am looking to write a type definition for an existing ES6 component.

Answer (score -2):

I am using react typescript react boilerplate provided by Microsoft
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter

I create a stateless component in typescript like this:

```
export interface IMyComponentProps {
   prop1: string;
   prop2: (event: React.MouseEvent) => void;
   prop3: number;
}

export class MyComponent extends React.Component<IMyComponentProps> {
    render(): JSX.Element {
        const {prop1, prop2} = this.props

        return (
            //My code here
            <button>prop1</button>
            <button>prop2</button>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer shows how to create a stateless component, rather than a stateless component type definition file.

Comment: This is how to write it in ts not how to declare a definition as the question asks.

Comment: I have initialized interface for the same.

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this.

```
export type YourComponentType = {
  props1,
  props2
}

const YourComponent = ({
  props1,
  props2,
  ...restProps //additional props if passed to components.
}: YourComponentType) => (
  <div>{props1}</div>
)

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I think this is an example of rewriting the component itself. I'd like to create a .d.ts file for an existing ES6 module. I've updated my question