# Type definition for react-native-checkbox

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to create a type definition file for [react-native-checkbox](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-checkbox). Here's what I have in the `.d.ts` file:

```js
declare module '@react-native-community/checkbox' {
  import * as React from 'react';

  interface CheckBoxProps {
    disabled?: boolean;
    value?: boolean;
    tintColors?: {
      true?: string;
      false?: string;
    };
    onChange?: () => void;
    onValueChange?: (value: boolean) => void;
  }

  export class CheckBox extends React.Component<CheckBoxProps> {}
}
```

But, when I use the `<CheckBox />` in my screens, I get the following error:

> JSX element type 'CheckBox' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)

What am I missing?

Comment: your component doesn't have `render` method and it seems you define component here... Is this intentional?

Comment: @zmii No, it's not intentional. What do I need to do?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html suggests you need to declare methods of the class as you are in typing fil... but your error suggests class definition from typing file is called when you imported it... basically there were no implementation at all... try adding console.log to see if this class was executed to not. apart from it look at this - https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/components/ ... maybe you don't really need to use definition file at all... at least I haven't wrote single file in years.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946979/how-do-i-create-a-typescript-type-definition-for-a-stateless-react-component